Routing problem in my Angular/springboot ecommerce project
Hi i can't understand why when i place order it say
POST http://localhost:9090/placeOrder/ 404 (Not Found)
In my angular i have
public placeOrder(orderForm: NgForm){
    console.log(this.orderDetails);
    this.productService.placeOrder(this.orderDetails, this.isSingleProductCheckout).subscribe(
      (resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        orderForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['/orderConfirm']);
      },
      (err) =>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }```
that goes to 


public placeOrder(orderDetails: OrderDetails, isCartCheckout){
return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:9090/placeOrder/"+isCartCheckout, orderDetails);
}
and it must talk to springboot in the OrderDetailController



@PreAuthorize("hasRole('User')")
@PostMapping({"/placeOrder/{isCartCheckout}"})
public void placeOrder(@PathVariable(name = "isCartCheckout") boolean isCartCheckout, @RequestBody OrderInput orderInput) {
orderDetailService.placeOrder(orderInput, isCartCheckout);
}

But it can't find anything 
Routing:


{
path: 'orderConfirm',
component: OrderConfirmationComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: ['User'] }
},




https://github.com/varadvk/e-commerce-youtube-ui/tree/main/src/app
it's pretty much the code from this tutorial but i added a string field in the order detail and order detail controller and in the angular form, and now angular print this


alternateContactNumber: "34534534534"
bookingDate:"26 Jun 2024"
contactNumber: "345345345345"
fullAddress: "asdfsdfsdfg"
fullName: "sdfgsdfsdf"
orderProductQuantityList:etc...```
but says 404 when trying to talk to the backend
It needed to talk to the backend and store the info of the order
